# AngularJS ng-repeat key, value pair access key on group by multiple fields

Tags: angularjs, group-by, multiple-columns, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm new to Angular and would like to learn the best way to handle a problem.
I want to access keys in my first ng-repeat grouped by multiple columns.

```html
<table width="100%" style="text-align: center;" data-role="table" data-mode="" class="ui-responsive ui-shadow">
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Id</th>
   <th>Course</th>
   <th>Module</th>
   <th>Subject</th>
   <th>Toc</th>
   <th>Chapter</th>
   <th>Activity Done</th>
   <th>Start</th>
   <th>End</th>
   <th>Time Spent</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody ng-repeat="(key, value) in sessions | groupBy: ['course','module','subject','toc','chapter']" id="tblSessionRpt">
  <tr ng-init="$index == 0 ? isOpen=true : isOpen=false">
   <td>
    <span ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen" style="cursor:pointer">
     <span ng-show="!isOpen">
      &nbsp; + &nbsp;
      <span> {{ $index+1 }} </span>
     </span>
     <span ng-show="isOpen">
      &nbsp; - &nbsp;
      <span> {{  $index+1 }} </span>
     </span>
    </span>
   </td>
   <td> {{ key.course }} </td>
   <td> {{ key.module }} </td>
   <td> {{ key.subject }} </td>
   <td> {{ key.toc }} </td>
   <td> {{ key.chapter }} </td>
   
   <td colspan='4' align="right"> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr ng-repeat="session in value" ng-show="isOpen">
   <td colspan='6'> &nbsp;</td>
   <td> {{ session.done }}</td>
   <td> {{ session.start }}</td>
   <td> {{ session.end }}</td>
   <td> {{ session.timespent }}</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

My JSON data is like :

```
$scope.sessions=[
{
    "id": 3518,
    "name": "content",
    "done": "A Happy Song",
    "start": "2015-11-23 11:11",
    "end": "2015-11-23 11:11",
    "timespent": "0",
    "course": "K-12",
    "module": "Std - 1",
    "subject": "English",
    "toc": "Unit - 01",
    "chapter": "A Happy Song",
    "content": null
},
{
    "id": 3520,
    "name": "content",
    "done": "A Happy Song",
    "start": "2015-11-23 11:11",
    "end": "2015-11-23 11:12",
    "timespent": "0",
    "course": "K-12",
    "module": "Std - 1",
    "subject": "Hindi",
    "toc": "Unit - 01",
    "chapter": "A Happy Song",
    "content": null
},
{
    "id": 3522,
    "name": "content",
    "done": "A Happy Song",
    "start": "2015-11-23 11:13",
    "end": "2015-11-23 11:13",
    "timespent": "0",
    "course": "K-12",
    "module": "Std - 1",
    "subject": "English",
    "toc": "Unit - 01",
    "chapter": "A Happy Song",
    "content": null
},
{
    "id": 3524,
    "name": "content",
    "done": "A Happy Song",
    "start": "2015-11-23 11:17",
    "end": "2015-11-23 11:17",
    "timespent": "0",
    "course": "K-12",
    "module": "Std - 1",
    "subject": "Marathi",
    "toc": "Unit - 02",
    "chapter": "A Happy Song",
    "content": null
},
{
    "id": 3537,
    "name": "content",
    "done": "A Happy Song",
    "start": "2015-11-23 11:47",
    "end": "2015-11-23 11:47",
    "timespent": "0",
    "course": "K-12",
    "module": "Std - 1",
    "subject": "English",
    "toc": "Unit - 03",
    "chapter": "A Happy Song",
    "content": null
}];
```

I want to data group by multiple columns i.e. 'course','module','subject','toc','chapter'

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

the most efficient way of sorting I usually do is to put your columns first in a array with it's designated keys in your data

```
$scope.cols = [
    {
        "name": "Course",
        "key": "course"
    },
    {
        "name": "Module",
        "key": "module"
    },
    {
        "name": "Subject"
        "key": "subject"
    },
    {
        "name": "Toc",
        "key": "toc"
    },
    {
        "name": "Chapter",
        "key": "chapter"
    },
    {
        "name": "Activity Done",
        "key": ""
    },
    {
        "name": "Start",
        "key": "start"
    },
    {
        "name": "End",
        "key": "end"
    },
    {
        "name": "Time Spent",
        "key": "timespent"
    }
];
```

then loop it in your template and add ng-click

```
<tr ng-repeat="col in cols" ng-click="onHeadingClicked(col)">
    {{col.name}}
</tr>
```

then create the `onHeadingClicked()` function that sorts your data.

```
$scope.onHeadingClicked = function (col) {
    var sorted = [];
    angular.forEach(sessions, function (col) {
        // Sorting algorithm here
    });

    $scope.sessions = sorted;
};
```

I don't use filters due to performance reasons, filter's run every time and thus executes that function so many many times so it would not a good idea putting it there. I use filters only if simple display manipulation is done.

Hope this helps