# Angular JS sorting rows with complex records

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

How can I sort a table in angularjs when the records are computed using a function? How should I have the sort function in contoller?

For example, two of my records are:

```
<td>{{object.lastName}}</td>
<td>{{getValue(objecct1, object2, 'string')}}</td>
```

and for header I have this:

`<th ng-click="order('string')">String<span ng-show="predicate === 'string'"`

I can sort based on lastName because it is not nested, but I cannot sort based on the record which comes from a getter function.

I think my problem is the predicate which I think cannot find the corresponding data to sort them.

Also in controller I have these lines:

```
$scope.predicate = 'lastName';
$scope.reverse = false;

$scope.order = function(predicate) {
    $scope.reverse = ($scope.predicate === predicate) ? !$scope.reverse : false;
    $scope.predicate = predicate;
};
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I just updated my answer I think that is what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

I am just wondering do you use `ng-repeat` to display your nested data? If yes try to check out [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33888029/angularjs-ng-repeat-key-value-pair-access-key-on-group-by-multiple-fields). My answer for your question would be pretty much the same with that

EDITED:

Just try to check out my answer in the post I linked here I will show you how I store my data and become accessible across the app by using `Service`.

```
.service("DataProvider", function () {
    var _data = [];
    var obj = {
        update: function () {
            // Do an $http to update your data
        },
        getCachedData: function () {
            return _data;
        }
    };

    return obj;
});
```

And so you can get your data easily around your app in a `controller`, `directive` or in another `service` by injecting your created service called `DataProvider`

```
.controller("YourControllerName", function ($scope, DataProvider) {
    // Here I will call getCached data every time this controller is called
    $scope.myData = DataProvider.getCachedData();

    // And your sorting function would pretty much be in here
    $scope.order = function () {
        // Do an sorting algo here
        var sorted = [];
        angular.forEach(sorted, function () {
            // Do your fancy sorting algo
        });

        $scope.myData = sorted;
    };
});
```

Comment: ok, but can you explain what function do you use for storing?

Comment: I just updated my answer I think that is what you are looking for